# ArcMap Intersect Tool is missing just one intersect point of two polyline shapefiles?

Tags: arcmap, tools, intersect, missing-data

I'm trying to find the intersect of 2 polyline shapefiles. One shapefile is a long line (of multiparts), the other shapefile is 11 straight lines that "fan out" radially. The ends of the first shapefile are snapped to around the midpoint of the first and last of the 11 lines, (i.e. the two radially-farthest lines) and crosses each of the other lines around their midway.

I need to know the exact X & Y location of the intersect points. **I've been running the intersect tool, then "add XY".** There should always be 11 intersect points (because one of the shapefiles is 11 straight lines), but **it is repeatedly missing the "last" point** (radially farthest to the right, or clockwise) and this messes up some data processing later on down the line (even if I manually add the point to the intersect points shapefile).

I've tried:
- running "repair geometry" first - I don't actually know what this does, but it didn't help
- converting both shapefiles to "singlepart" (because as is, the first consists of multiple parts of each line segment that I mapped, and the second is 11 lines) then running the intersect on the singlepart shapefiles
(neither worked)

does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work, and what I can do to fix this?

Comment: What coordinate systems are the layers in and what tolerance did you use when running the Intersect tool?

Comment: Try output as lines,  if result not empty, members of intersect share segment, no point as a result. Worth checking if processing extent is large enough.